# Laravel Multi js Include

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel so my problem is that I am trying to add multiple script files to my blade.php page using this code:

```
{{       
       HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js');
       HTML::script('js/Chart.js');
}}
```

without any results , am I doing anything wrong or misunderstood some concept, please specify the best way to achieve my goal

only first include is working, the second one is not including

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have line breaks inside Blade tags (at least not in Laravel 3). What you need to do is to add `{{ ... }}` for every `HTML::` you have.

```
{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js'); }}
{{ HTML::script('js/Chart.js'); }}
```

Comment: Thanks ! is there a much more beautiful, organized way to include several includes ?